# I can't figure out how to loop with this error : a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Hi :) I would like to know if for each modality (df.A == 'First' and df.B = 'Second'), if for the column df.B the rows are equal (or not) to the first row (df['B'][0]).

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | None |
| First | 2 | None |
| First | 3 | None |
| Second | 2 | None |
| Second | 2 | None |
| Second | 2 | None |

The output should be :

- For the modality First, is 1 equal to 2 and 3 ? False.
- For the modality Second, is 2 equal to 2 and 2 ? True

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | None |
| First | 2 | False |
| First | 3 | False |
| Second | 2 | None |
| Second | 2 | True |
| Second | 2 | True |

I've tried this code :

```
def equal(df) :
    arr = df['A'].unique()
    arr = arr.tolist()
    dfd = df.copy()
    for i in arr : 
        for m in range(1, len(dfd['A']==i)) :
            if dfd['B'][m] == dfd['B'][0] :
                dfd['C'][m] == True
            else :
                dfd['C'][m] == False
equal(HoldingsLegal)
```

But I got this error :

:9: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the numbers in the first and the second columns are the same, the third column should be True? Is it what you want?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC this is what you want:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform("nunique").eq(1)
#        A  B      C
#0   First  1  False
#1   First  2  False
#2   First  3  False
#3  Second  2   True
#4  Second  2   True
#5  Second  2   True
```

If you need to turn the first values of every group to `None`, you can do this:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('A').head(1).index,'C'] = None
        A  B    C
#0   First  1  NaN
#1   First  2  0.0
#2   First  3  0.0
#3  Second  2  NaN
#4  Second  2  1.0
#5  Second  2  1.0
```

Comment: @ValerieGrimault I'm happy to help :D